# Application losing focus causes window death

Tags: codenameone

On **Techno** phones we discovered that whenever the application loses focus (even through actions like file picker), it doesn't resume, we got this stack trace from logcat

```
06-16 07:55:31.943 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.tattara.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
06-16 07:55:32.450 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:33.477 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:33.711 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:35.081 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:35.081 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:35.082 253-15067/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=1003; mark=1003
06-16 07:55:35.082 253-15067/? D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.tattara.com get result from proxy gai_error = 11
06-16 07:55:35.082 253-15067/? D/libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = api.tattara.com, class = 1, type = 1
06-16 07:55:35.082 253-15067/? D/libc-netbsd: res_queryN name = api.tattara.com succeed
06-16 07:55:35.083 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.tattara.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
06-16 07:55:35.478 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:36.948 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:55:37.387 14808-14888/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.tattara.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
06-16 07:57:54.994 893-2651/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{d9bd5a4 u0 com.encentral.tattara.mobile/com.encentral.tattara.mobile.ApplicationStub}
```

**Note** that this only happens on Techno Phones, other phones don't have the same issue. 
And this test was conducted on 3 different Techno phones running Andriod 6.0. 
What can we do about it?

Comment: This log doesn't say much, are you seeing an ANR on the android play portal?

Comment: I just tried the Kitchen Sink II demo on the same Techno Andriod 6.0 phone, and it was exactly the same problem. Am not seeing an ANR, it just doesn't resume after app loses focus

Comment: Are developer options enabled in the device? In Settings under developer options check that `Don't keep activities` is disabled. Also check other flags like background process limit, inactive apps etc.

Comment: I will check that later but other applications are fine.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog any progress on this? I think you will need to get access to a techno phone and see the anomalous for yourself. Thanks.

Comment: You can connect the device with a cable and look at logcat/DDMS output to see if there are error logs. Alternatively you can use include sources and debug using Android Studio on the device. We can't have every Android device out there as there are 24,000 Android device types so we need the help of the community here...

Comment: After fiddling with the source code, I moved  this line  `AndroidImplementation.startContext(this);`  from the `onResume()` method of **ApplicationStub.java** to the `onCreate()` method, and this seems to have solved the issue. Any reason why it was put in `onResume()` in the first place?

Comment: I reverted back all my changes ,discovered the problem wasn't from `onResume()` but in `reinit(Object i)` of **AndriodImplementation.java**, specifically `instance.init(i);` 
Based on the comment I saw in the code, I discovered that you actually did solve this issue, didn't just work for Tecno. 
So inside `reinit` I checked if it's a Tecno phone and only call `Display.init(i); return;`.Based on this hack, problem seems to be 80% solved, 20% arises when "Don't keep activities" is on, this causes the user not to be able to get result from other Android activities, e.g. picking an image